# How to unit test createQueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have this method:

```
public function findAllBy(?string $categoryId): array
    {
        $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p')
            ->from(Product::class, 'p');

        if (null !== $categoryId) {
            $qb->from(Category::class, 'cc')
               ->join(CategoryProduct::class, 'cp', Join::WITH, 'p.id = cp.product_id')
               ->join(Category::class, 'c', Join::WITH, 'cp.category_id = c.id')
               ->where('cc.id = :id')
               ->andWhere('cc.left <= c.left')
               ->andWhere('cc.right >= c.right')
               ->setParameter('id', $categoryId, 'uuid');
        }

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

I am trying to test it this way ( obviously not the correct one ):

```
public function testFindAllProductsByFilters():void
    {
        $entityRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(EntityRepository::class);
        $entityManagerMock = $this->createMock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $entityManagerMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->with(Product::class)
            ->willReturn($entityRepositoryMock);
        $entityManagerMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('createQueryBuilder')
            ->willReturn($entityRepositoryMock);

        $this->repository = new DoctrineProductRepository($entityManagerMock);
        $this->assertIsArray($this->repository->findAllBy(ProductFactory::CATEGORY_ID_FIRST));
    }
```

The error I get:
1)

> App\Tests\Unit\Infrastructure\Domain\Model\Product\DoctrineProductRepositoryTest::testFindAllProductsByFilters
> Error: Call to a member function from() on null

Is this piece of code even testable by Unit Test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you should [not mock what you don't own](https://8thlight.com/blog/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html), my suggestion is to avoid unit tests in this kind of scenarios.
Moreover I would not use (abuse) a mock (a test double in general) as you're testing the implementation and not the behaviour of your SUT.

Let's see an example

```
class Foo()
{
  public function doSomething(): int
  {
    // some heavy logic here
  }
}

class Bar()
{
  public function doSomething(Foo $foo): int
  {
    $result = $foo->doSomething();
    // other elaboration upon $result
  } 
}
```

That's a deliberately trivial example of course. If you use a test double in `Bar` test, you would write something like`

```
$fooMock->expects($this->once())
  ->method('doSomething')
  ->willReturn(1);
```

Let's say that `Foo` changes it's public API, renaming `doSomething` to `doSomethingElse`. What happens? You need to change the test aswell even if `Foo` behaviour didn't changed at all.

As said before it's a trivial example but should give you an idea.